# AWS: Internet facing and Internal ALBs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I accidentally attached same instance with two target groups, of which one is selected for Internet facing and another is for Internal ALB.
I had two different paths set for health checks for corresponding ALBs.

Even though subnets selected while creating ALBs are different(different subnet for Zone), how both ALBs are hitting corresponding healthcheck paths in the only instance running on subnet configured for internetfacing traffic??

I assumed ALBs should hit instances which are running in configured subnets, not hit instances running in other Subnets.

What is the intended behavior for this setup?

BRs,
Kiran

Answer (score 2):

By default, all subnets can communicate with each other. So, a Load Balancer in Subnet A can still perform health checks against instances in Subnet B.

The 'configured subnets' specify where the Load Balancer interfaces with the VPC (shown as Elastic Network Interfaces, ENIs). From that entry point, they can communicate with the other subnets.

Comment: I know that depending on rules in security group, ACL and routetable, subenets can communicate with each other. Whole idea of LB is to load balance targets running on configured AZs(one subnet per instance). I find it not intuitive for LB communicating with instance  running in other subnets.

Comment: On the contrary, it is required! For example, imagine a VPC with a public subnet and a private subnet. The Load Balancer can be in the public subnet because it is receiving requests from the Internet. It then forwards the requests to servers in the private subnet. This is better from a security perspective because the instances are not accessible from the Internet, and only the Load Balancer is publicly exposed. This *requires* the Load Balancer to communicate with instances in a different subnet.

Comment: Please refer this link. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internal-load-balancers.html 
Create an Internet-facing load balancer and register the web servers with it. Create an internal load balancer and register the database servers with it. The web servers receive requests from the Internet-facing load balancer and send requests for the database servers to the internal load balancer. The database servers receive requests from the internal load balancer.